# Polymer iron pages same form ID between element

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-1.0

I try to make 2 page (signin and signup) using app-route and iron-pages, which both of them contain form with same form id. This is the [Sign In template](http://pastebin.com/QDwqWNGS) and the [Sign In submitForm script](http://pastebin.com/mwWVjVHx). This is the [Sign Up template](http://pastebin.com/x5Mbj9Y6) and the [Sign Up submitForm script](http://pastebin.com/hkaVUzEH).

When I click submit button in signup page, validation always return false (no input error). When I change the form ID so signin form ID different with signup form ID, I can do signup correctly. Is it a right behaviour? I think I can use same ID to both of the form, since they're in different element.

Comment: have you tried using `this.$.form` instead of `document.getElementById` and similarly for other fields also

Comment: Ah you're right @a1626. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @a1626, I should use this.$.form which is search for local DOM instead of document.getElementById.